# How to position a Widget in a Stack, but without matching parent's width/height?

Tags: dart, flutter

I want to position a widget in the top center of my Stack, but it is getting stretched to the parent's width like the screenshot below:

[image]

And this is the code I am using:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: key,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Just a test app"),
      ),
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Positioned(
            left: 0,
            right: 0,
            child: Card(
              child: Text("A variable sized text"),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

What I am trying to achieve is this (but inside a Stack):
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your `Card` into an `Align` or `Center`:

```
 Stack(
    children: <Widget>[
      Positioned( 
        top: 50,
        left: 0,
        right: 0,
        child: Center(
          child: Card(
            child: Text("A variable sized text"),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      Align(
        alignment: Alignment.topCenter, //that also works
        child: Card(
          child: Text("Another variable sized text"),
        ),
      )
    ],
  ),
```

Comment: The `Positioned` is pointless. We can use `Align` combined with `Alignment.topCenter`